# Book bus in Laos

Tags: buses, laos

Do anyone have experience booking public bus tickets in Laos to travel among tourist destinations like Muang Xay, Luang Namtha, Phonsavan...I'd prefer some bus lines having more foreign travellers.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To search information in Laos you can go with http://www.laos-guide-999.com/travel-by-bus.html It displays many useful tips about buses in Lao.

One more website I'd to use is Baolau to book train, bus tickets in Laos, Thailand, Cambodia & Vietnam. I find they had their article about [bus routes in Laos](http://www.baolau.com/blog/bus-in-laos/) Take it for your reference.
Cheers.

Comment: Do you know what bus lines have more tourists?

Comment: Do you work for laos-guide-999.com?